# Video conversion tool and video tag editor

Tags: open-source, video, media-converter

Want convert my video archive to "consolidated" format. Because i have many different movies, some in original language, some others with dubbing, also want preserve original movie title as well as translated one, for some movies want include multiple subtitles etc... so decided to use the MKV container format.

Looking for a best toolset (converting and tag-editing) with the following features.

- should convert all movies with h264 and into MKV container
- the converted movies should be playable on iPhone 4s (AFAIK here are MKV players for IOS), on Dreambox (VU+ DUO) and in Kodi (XBMC).
- the program should allow conversion in batch mode (queuing many movies for conversion)
- best solution for me would be some open-source, command line conversion tool what already compiled and installable in cygwin - and allows me using cygwin's bash scripting.
- some tool for editing MKV video tags.

Some recommendation how to convert my movie archive to common format, with as little as possible manual work?